# Is the reflexive infinitive really a passive infinitive?

Tags: verbs, infinitive, passive, reflexive

Is the reflexive infinitive (e.g., *farsi*) really a passive infinitive?

Comment: No it's not. It's a reflexive infinitive - reflexive and passive are different voices. Why do you think they are the same?